# gwt: How to use a widget which is created by onClick in another event?

Tags: events, gwt, variable-declaration

i need to use the widget `shapei` (which is created by onClick) at this place: `public void onElementConnect(ElementConnectEvent event) {}....if(connected.equals(**shapei**.connectedWidget)){`. How can i solve this? It would be great, if someone can help me! Here is the full code:

```
public class Projekt implements EntryPoint {

    private RootPanel rootPanel;

    public void onModuleLoad() {

         rootPanel = RootPanel.get("gwtContainer");
         rootPanel.setSize("1902", "868");

         final AbsolutePanel boundaryPanel = new AbsolutePanel();
         boundaryPanel.setStyleName("frame1");
         boundaryPanel.setSize("1455px", "600px");       

         final Diagram diagram = new Diagram(boundaryPanel);

         RootPanel.get().add(boundaryPanel, 446, 242);

         final Connector con = new Connector(100, 300, 300, 500);

         Button la = new Button("Push");
         la.setSize("200", "200");
         boundaryPanel.add(la);

         Button la2 = new Button("Push2");
         la2.setSize("200", "200");
         boundaryPanel.add(la2);

         Image img2 = new Image("images/variable.svg");
         img2.setSize("200", "200");
         boundaryPanel.add(img2, 200,200);

         final Shape shapei2 = new Shape(img2);
         shapei2.showOnDiagram(diagram);

         la.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                 final Image img = new Image("images/concrete.svg");
                 img.setSize("200", "200");
                 boundaryPanel.add(img, 200,200);
                 Shape shapei = new Shape(img);
                 shapei.showOnDiagram(diagram);}

            public void onElementConnect(ElementConnectEvent event) {
                       if (con.startEndPoint.isGluedToConnectionPoint()) {
                           Widget connected = con.startEndPoint.gluedConnectionPoint.parentWidget;
                           if(connected.equals(shapei.connectedWidget)){
                         Image logo = new Image("images/xor.svg");
                         logo.setSize("100", "100");
                         boundaryPanel.add(logo);
                       }
                           else if(connected.equals(shapei2.connectedWidget)){
                                Image logo2 = new Image("images/and.svg");
                             logo2.setSize("100", "100");
                             boundaryPanel.add(logo2);
                           };
                     }}

            }

         );
         la2.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {

                     con.showOnDiagram(diagram);
                }

             });




}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The recommended option**

You should move the declaration of the shapei outside the anonymous callback method. The reference falls out of scope once the onClick method completes. If you move a declaration to the global scope you can access it in other methods. This won't look so strange if you move the view parts to an external class instead of doing it all in your EntryPoint class btw. You can use something like a simple Activity called DiagramActivity and in your entry point you simply call start on the activity.

public class Projekt implements EntryPoint {

```
private RootPanel rootPanel;

Shape shapei;

public void onModuleLoad() {
   ....
}
```

**Another Option**
If you add it to the DOM, you can look it up using the Document class or GwtQuery. This can be much slower though.